# Combine all possible characters with days of the week

Tags: java, arrays, string, combinations, permutation

I have to extract all the combinations of the characters "A, B, C, D, E, F, G", and then combine it with the days of the week so that the result is:

```
Monday AB
Tuesday AC
Wednesday AD
Thursday AE
Friday AF
Saturday AG
Monday BA
Tuesday BC
Wednesday BD
....
```

Logrea make the combination of characters but I can not combine with the days, I would greatly appreciate the help.

cycles while, arrays and for.

```
public class daysP {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] elements = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G".split(",");
        int r = elements.length; 
        combination(elements, "",2, r);
    }

    private static void combina(String[] elem, String act, int n, int r) {
        String[] di=new String[5];
        days[0]="Monday";
        days[1]="Tuesday ";
        days[2]="Wednesday";
        days[3]="Thursday";
        days[4]="Friday";
        days[5]="Saturday";

        if (n == 0) {            
            for (int x=0;x<7;)
            {   
                System.out.println(days[x]+act);x++;
            }
        } 
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                if (!act.contains(elem[i]))
                    combina(elem, act + elem[i] + "", n - 1, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the expected result is:

```
Monday AB
Tuesday AC
Wednesday AD
Thursday AE
Friday AF
Saturday AG
Monday BA
Tuesday BC
Wednesday BD
..............
```

until `GF`, which would be the last combination

the actual result is:

```
MondayAB
Tuesday AB
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code for easier comprehension

Comment: Java knows the names of the days in many languages. Use `DayOfWeek.getDisplayName()`.

Comment: It seems that combinations of a letter with itself, like `AA`, `BB`, etc., should be skipped. Have I understood this correctly? And Sunday should be skipped too?

Comment: yes, repeated combinations such as AA BB are also skipped

Answer (score 2):

We can generate this output with a double loop.  The logic below is that we use separate indices for the first and last letters, and as well as the day of week which gets printed.  We use the mod of the `counter` variable to determine which day gets printed, so this counter wraps around each of the six days in your defined week.

```
String[] days = new String[6];
days[0] = "Monday";
days[1] = "Tuesday";
days[2] = "Wednesday";
days[3] = "Thursday";
days[4] = "Friday";
days[5] = "Saturday";
int NUM_CHARS = 7;

int counter = 0;

for (int i=0; i < NUM_CHARS; ++i) {
    String first = Character.toString((char)(i + 65));
    for (int j=0; j < NUM_CHARS; ++j) {
        if (i == j) continue;
        String second = Character.toString((char)(j + 65));
        String day = days[counter % days.length];
        ++counter;

        System.out.println(day + " " + first + second);
    }
}

Monday AB
Tuesday AC
Wednesday AD
Thursday AE
Friday AF
Saturday AG
Monday BA
Tuesday BC
Wednesday BD
...
Thursday GD
Friday GE
Saturday GF
```